# Multiple probabilities to single

Tags: expected-value, games

This is a pretty simple question.

If I win 7 dollars with a probability of 0.33, and 3 dollars with a probability of 0.35, can I substitue this multiscenario event to a single event of winning 7(33/68) + 3(35/68) with a probability of 0.68.

My goal is, given a money game, to quickly compare which side is more advantageous (without having to calculate the expected value of the game).
When it is a simple problem, it's all fine. Like: 
1. I receive 30 dollars if $x$ happens and I pay 10 dollars if $x$ doesn't happen, I can easily compare 30/40 with the probability of $x$ not happening, if it's bigger, then it's worth it, else it isn't.

But multiscenario problems are hard for me to deal with. For example: 
2. I receive 25 dollars if $y$ happens and 12 dollars if $z$ happens, and I pay 32 dollars if $k$ happens and 19 dollars if $p$ happens , where $y,z,k$, and $p$ are independent events, with $P(y) + P(z) = 1 - P(k) - P(p)$.

What is a quick way (without evaluating the expected value) to tell if it's worth it?
I was thinking of reducing each of the 2 multiscenario events in 2 single-scenario events, and deal like in the case of 1.

Comment: What happens when any of events $y$, $z$, $k$, or $p$ doesn't occur? Do you win/lose money? How much? What is the objective criteria to determine "if it's worth it"? Expected value (strictly) positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this directly contradicts the premise of the question, but why not just grind through the math and compute the expected value, given that it's exactly what you want anyway.

For the example in your question, the expected values aren't the same, which ought to indicate that your approach is flawed. To wit:

```
>> 7*(1/3) + 3*0.35
  ans =
    3.3833
```

but

```
>> (7*(33/68) + 3*(35/68)) * 0.68
  ans =
    3.3600
```

Just in case you're getting mixed up on the definition of expected value, it's 
$$\mathbb{E}(X) = x_1P(X=x_1) + x_2P(X=x_2) + \cdots + x_nP(X=x_n)$$
where $x_i$ are the values that $X$ can take. I usually think of it as  a weighted average of the possible values for $X$, where the probabilities are the weights. Wikipedia (and any intro textbook) have lots more details.

For your first example, a 40 doesn't really enter into the computations. Let's call that random variable Y. Then
$$\mathbb{E}(Y) = P(x) \cdot 30 + (1-P(x))\cdot(-10)$$
You'd typically plug in a value for P(x), and compare the resulting value to zero. If that is greater than zero, then the game is a "good deal" for you.

For your second example, it's not possible to compute an expected value because your probabilities aren't actually known. For example, we could set $P(y)$, $P(z)$, $P(k)$, and $P(p)$ all to $0.25$. This satisfies your constraint that $P(y) + P(z) = 1 - P(p) - P(k)$, and it makes the resulting expected value very negative:
$$\mathbb{E}(Z)=0.25 \cdot 25 + 0.25 \cdot 12 + 0.25 \cdot (-32) + 0.25\cdot(-19)=(-3.5)$$
On the other hand, we could also set $P(y)=1$ and the rest to $0$. In this case, the expected value is 25, which is a vastly better deal for you. Instead of looking for a heuristic, you might want to find out what else you know about the relationships between $y,z,p,$ and $k$